# Limitations to modifying rt.jar

Tags: java, internals, jvm-hotspot

What are the limitations when modifying classes in rt.jar.  I realize this is generally specific to the version and vendor of the JRE.  I've found that Hotspot in the Sun 1.6 VM, for instance, doesn't like if you add fields to java.lang.Object as it has hard-coded assumptions about the size of Object.  However, if I modify significant portions of the classes in rt.jar, I get spurious ClassNotFoundErrors at runtime for classes that are definitely in my jar.  I've tried modifying rt.jar in place as well as superseding it with the various -Xbootclasspath parameters.

I don't really know where to look for documentation on this sort of thing, I can't find anything in the OpenJDK docs, for instance.

Comment: I'm curious about your reasons for doing this?

Comment: add a field to Object will cost you a lot of memory space and garbage collection time.

Comment: I'd also be curious why you feel the need to edit the base classes. There's probably another way to solve the problem besides building non-portable changes into the JDK classes.

Comment: If you are really sure you want to edit the base class, did you check whether you could achieve what you wanted using AspectJ, or as Amir said, using ASM? http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/

Comment: I am trying to add copy-on-write semantics to all field writes so that they can be automatically check-pointed and rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a byte code instrumentation library to achieve what you want?  You could use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) + [java.lang.instrument](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), for JDK's greater than or equal to 5.0

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing, in fact.  The problem is that I can't get at certain core classes with this technique because they are already loaded by the time I get to run my instrumentation code.  My fall back is to modify these classes (or the entire rt.jar) a priori  and this is where I'm running into trouble.

Comment: My two cents are that when you try to redefine these classes, you might get unmodifiableClassException